# Sequence For Loop

Tags: java, for-loop, sequence

I'm trying to create a for loop to sequentially add 4 to a random value (r) as many times as the value of (n).

I came up with this:

```
for (int counter = 1; counter <=n; counter++){
    System.out.println(a = a + 4);
}
```

The thing is if the random value were to be 10 for example, it will start counting from 14, 18, 22.

I want it to start counting at the number itself so the results are 10, 14, 18 not to start +4 from the random number selected.

Answer (score 3):

Change your loop body to:

```
System.println(a);
a += 4;
```

Or the whole loop to

```
for (int counter = 1; counter <=n; counter++, a += 4){
  System.out.println(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Then do not increase `a` before printing it.
`a = a + 4` will first increment `a` by 4 store the result in `a` and only then print it.

What you need is :

```
for (int counter = 1; counter <=n; counter++){
    System.out.println(a);
    a += 4;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Print the current number before adding 4 to it, then.

```
System.out.println(a); // print the number
a = a + 4; // THEN add 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int counter = 1; counter <=n; counter++){
    System.out.println(a+4*(counter-1));
}
```

Comment: It's always good to describe the code that you post and why it solves the problem.